# Implement OnTouch listener in timer

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I am new to Android and I have a problem.
I'm trying to create a app that when you hold down a button, a timer starts. If you let go of the pressed button the timer reset itself. It will play a sound if you manage to hold till the timers reach zero.   I manage, with some ugly code, to have clickable button which starts a timer, but I can't implement the `OnTouch` listener.

How do I change the `OnCLick` to a `OnTouch`  in this code?

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final String tag = "Main";
    private KarinCountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
    private Button startB;
    private TextView text;


    private final long startTime = 900000;    //15 min 1800000

    
    private final long interval = 1000;
    
    SoundManager mymanager;                           //sound 
    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
            startB.setOnClickListener(this);

            
            text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    
        countDownTimer = new KarinCountDownTimer(startTime,interval);
        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime));
            
            
            mymanager = new SoundManager(this);                     
        }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (!timerHasStarted)
                {
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    timerHasStarted = true;
                    startB.setText("Start");
                
                }
            else
                {

                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    timerHasStarted = false;
                    startB.setText("RESET");
                }
        }

    // CountDownTimer class
    public class KarinCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
        {

            public KarinCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
                {
                    super(startTime, interval);
                }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
                {
                    text.setText("Time's up!");                      
                
                    
                    mymanager.playSound(R.raw.zen_sound1);
                
                
                    
                }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
                {
                    text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished);
        
                }
            
        }
    protected void onPause(){
        mymanager.stopSound();
        super.onPause();
        
    }
    protected void onDestroy(){
        mymanager.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Ive tried                                                                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             countDownTimer.start();
    timerHasStarted = true;
            } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
             countDownTimer.cancel();
    timerHasStarted = false;

            return true;
        }